# Recursion: design a recursive function called replicate_recur which will receive two arguments:

Tags: python, recursion

The below code is a recursive function which takes two arguments and return something  like `[5,5,5]`.

```
def recursive(times, data):  
    if not isinstance(times,int):  
         raise ValueError("times must be an int")  
    if not (isinstance(data,int) or isinstance(data, str)):  
        raise ValueError("data must be an int or a string")  
    if times <= 0:  
        return []  
    return [data] + recursive(times, data - 1)  

print(recursive(3, 5))
```

Why is the code throwing a recursive error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to think how we would repeat any data item N times recursively:

- If `times` is 0 or less, we return an empty list, as per the requirements.
- If `times` is greater than 0, we return list that has `data` ones and another `times - 1` repetitions of data, recursively.

Another requirement is to check the validity of the arguments and raise a `ValueError` if they are invalid. While this can be done in the same recursive function, this carries a performance hit, as we'll do the same validation `times` times. The textbook solution for this is to separate the function to two - an "outer" function that handles the validations and and "inner" function that handles the recursive logic.

Put it all together, and you'll get something like this:

```
def replicate_recur(times, data):
    if not isinstance(times, int):
        raise ValueError("times must be an int")

    return real_replicate_recur(times, data)

def real_replicate_recur(times, data):
    if times <= 0:
        return []

    return [data] + real_replicate_recur(times - 1, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to store the result of current recursive call.

```
def replicate_recur(times, data, ret=None):
    if not ret:
        ret = []
    ret.append(data)
    times -= 1
    if not times:
        return ret
    return replicate_recur(times, data, ret)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, helped a lot, I refactored the code to make it work. now it's working well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

your code actually is supposed to run fine, the problem is that base case takes the items variable into consideration while the recursive function decrements the data arguments instead of decrementing the times argument